# Make function comply with CQS principle

Tags: c#

The function below accepts a hierarchical structure and returns a flat list of captions.

There are few variations on the returned data:

1. If `showTotals` is `true`, and  `root` has children (`if(!root.IsEmpty)`) - `"RootCaption"` needs to be added as a first element of the list.
2. If `showTotals` is `false` - all the children with a property `IsTotal == true` need to be filtered out from the result.

Ideally, I would like to see something like the pseudo code below:

```
public List<string> GetTreeCaptions(Tree root, bool showTotals)
{
    var subTreesCaptions= GetSubTreesCaptionsByShowTotals(root, showTotals);
    var rootCaption = GetRootCaption(root, showTotals);

    var headers = new List<string>(rootCaption);
    headers.AddRange(subTreesCaptions);

    return headers;
}
```

But, the implementation of the inner functions `GetSubTreesCaptionsByShowTotals` and `GetRootCaption` would be very much alike the current implementation, so I think it would be an overkill and wouldn't add anything to the readability.

Does anyone have any pointers on how to improve the code below to make it compliant with the [Command Query Separation principle](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/CommandQuerySeparation.html)?

Just to make it clear, I treat the `if` conditions in this code as `queries` and list modifications as `commands`.

```
public List<string> GetTreeCaptions(Tree root, bool showTotals)
    {
        var headers = new List<string>();
        var flatTree = root.SubTrees.Traverse(x => x.SubTree);

        if (!showTotals)
        {
            flatTree = flatTree.Where(n => n.IsTotal == false);
        }
        else{
            if(!root.IsEmpty){
                headers.Add("RootCaption");
            }
        }

        headers.AddRange(flatTree.Caption);

        return headers;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

The method you posted doesn't seem to modify the state of the object, nor any of the passed in parameters. As such, it doesn't violate the Command Query Separation principle. Or at least it *seems* it doesn't modify anything. But if it does, then you have a big problem with naming, because from what I can see here, if the current object or a parameter is modified, it's really not obvious.

On the other hand, there are a few things I don't understand about this code.

Why not move the `root.is empty()` check to the top, and return early?

What is the purpose of this code?

```
    if (!showRoot)
    {
        flatTree.Where(n => n.IsTotal == false);
    }
```

It looks like it runs a query but doesn't store the result. So then what's the point?

Comment: you're right, there should be an assignment in that line.
I modified my code to reflect that. And, I also added more details about my problem